# not able to change button color with onClick event, button becomes purple

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, data-binding, onclick

I want to change the color of a button once pressed to whatever color that I created in colors/drawables but buttons are not changing as they intended. I think I tried everything on this site yet could not find a solution. `android:backgroundTint` is not becoming a solution. I just want to change my colors to any color that I created rather than purple.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="254dp"
    android:layout_height="62dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:text="Press"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.496"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.857" />
```

themes;

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<style name="Theme.YdsYokdil" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>    
</style>
```

themes(night)

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<style name="Theme.YdsYokdil" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_200</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/black</item>>
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_200</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
</style>
```

my code(to change the color)

```
var isRedButtonsClicked = true

    fun colorButtonsRed() {
        binding.button.setBackgroundColor(R.color.red)
    }
     binding.button.setOnClickListener {
        when (isRedButtonsClicked) {
            true -> colorButtonsRed()
        } 
        setContentView(binding.root)
```

Comment: Also that `setContentView` inside onClickListenet is weird and not needed

Comment: @Amin when I delete `setContentView(binding.root)` the app is not opening, giving white screen. I don't know if this two are related

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setBackgroundColor` needs a color int (`0xFFFF0000` for example which is a red color in argb format) `R.color.red` is a ColorRes (resource identifier from R)

In order to get a color from those `R.color.xxx` we should use `ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.xxx)`

So change your code to

```
fun colorButtonsRed() {
    binding.button.setBackgroundColor(
        ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.red)
    )
}
```

Comment: '(context, R.color.red)' what context do here? it giving error

Comment: okay I should have refer (context: this, R.color.red) you are a savior! thank you. this is worked. :)